# How to format date from Excel recordset?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I get data from SQL Server and now I want to copy it in Excel worksheet.

I tried to format "start_date" but it applied the format only on the first column, all others display as stored in SQL Server.

```vb
Sub ReadMBDataFromSQL()
    Dim Server_Name, Database_Name, User_ID, Password, SQLStr As String

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = ""
    Database_Name = ""
    User_ID = ""
    Password = ""
    SQLStr = "SELECT lot, po, start_date, input_sponge_type, input_sponge_type FROM PalladiumNitrateMB WHERE start_date >= '" & Format(Range("start"), "mm-dd-yyyy") & "' AND start_date < '" & Format(Range("end"), "mm-dd-yyyy") & "' ORDER BY lot ASC"

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic

    With Worksheets("PdNitrateMassBalance").Range("A5:N600")
        RS("start_date") = Format(RS("start_date"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by modifying of the SQL query, i request the date with
`convert(varchar,start_date,103)`

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this part

```
With Worksheets("PdNitrateMassBalance").Range("A5:N600")
    RS("start_date") = Format(RS("start_date"), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset RS
End With
```

With this

```
With Worksheets("PdNitrateMassBalance")
    With .Range("A5:N600")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With
    FixDatesFromYYYY_MM_DD .Range("A:A"), "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
```

And additional sub:

```
Sub FixDatesFromYYYY_MM_DD(DatesRange As Range, Format As String)
Dim r As Range
Dim firstDash As Integer, secondDash As Integer, i As Integer

For Each r In DatesRange
    If Not r.Value = "" Then
        firstDash = 0
        secondDash = 0
        For i = 1 To Len(r.Text)
            If Mid(r.Text, i, 1) = "-" Then
                If Not firstDash = 0 Then
                    secondDash = i
                    Exit For
                Else
                    firstDash = i
                End If
            End If
        Next

        With r
            .Value = DateSerial(Left(r.Text, 4), Mid(r.Text, firstDash + 1, IIf(secondDash = 7, 1, 2)), Mid(r.Text, secondDash + 1))
            .NumberFormat = Format
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Update**
Added a sub to convert dates from "yyyy-mm-dd" text format.

Comment: It doesn't help because data from SQL is coming like 2020-01-11 and it ignores the cell formats... i have to format data before copy to excel worksheet

Comment: @MartinM Updated my answer just after your answer